# Filter markers in a Leaflet featureGroup

Tags: leaflet

I've a featureGroup with custom (extended) circle markers (custom options).
(database results, markers added to featureGroup - NO Geojson !)

Is it possible to add a filter (dynamically) based on one of the custom options (a simple numeric value) ?

I want to associate it with a slider.

I struggle with this for days :-((

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the featureGroup on each slider change with `eachLayer(function (layer)`, using either `layer.setOpacity(0)` or `layer.setOpacity(1)` depending on whether a marker should be shown or hidden...of course this approach will not work so well with large volumes of markers. You may need to switch into canvas mode for this approach(using `L_PREFER_CANVAS = true`)

Additionally, there is an ongoing discussion about this on the Github Issues board.https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4

Comment: Still strugling: This is my code so far;     `map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
     var obj = layer.options;
     for(var prop in obj) {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
       if(obj[prop] >= myValue) {
        //Found myValue!
        layer.setOpacity(1);
       } else {
        layer.setOpacity(0);
       }
      }
     }
    }); `                                                                             But get an error: **Uncaught TypeError: layer.setOpacity is not a function**. I would appreciate it very much if you can provide me a simple example.

Comment: Can you try using `myFeatureGroup.eachLayer` instead of `map.eachLayer`?